# Fast column slices in PyTables

Tags: python, arrays, slice, transpose, pytables

I have a large CArray of integers in PyTables (1 million rows, 50,000 columns):

```
In [22]: fmat
Out[22]: 
/fmat (CArray(1025461, 54123), shuffle, blosc(5)) ''
  atom := Int32Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (9, 54123)
```

Selecting rows is fine:

```
In [24]: %timeit fmat[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.5 µs per loop
```

But selecting columns takes forever:

```
In [25]: %timeit fmat[:,0]
1 loop, best of 3: 25 s per loop
```

Is there an efficient way to index columns, or transpose the array, to allow fast slices?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the `chunkshape` parameter when creating the array.

If one only needs column slices, just set the column as the chunkshape. For example, for an NxP matrix (N rows and P columns), choose:

`fmat = f.create_carray(f.root, 'fmat', tb.Int32Atom(), 
                       shape=(N, P), filters=filters,
                       chunkshape=[N,1])`